# Can I comment on YouTube videos using Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

Can commenting on YouTube videos (including signing into Google+, etc) happen on Tor Browser, or is it not implemented? I'm on an Ubuntu Linux build.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't reply, like or dislike comments. When I try a window pops up and closes again immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You may sign in to Google+ and YouTube, and comment on YouTube. However, you lose anonymity as soon as you do so.

In addition, you will be marked as a Tor user. Once somebody is marked as a Tor user, it becomes easier for adversaries to test the hypothesis of if it was you who visited a particular site or wrote a particular comment even if you do not sign in, that is if adversaries choose to do so in some future point.

Comment: Heya, thanks for the answer. Ok so then why cant I do this? I can sign into the google system but when it comes to comment a popup window opens and closes very quickly and no commenting can be done. The anonymity factor is held up by it being an anonymous account signed up for anonymously.

Comment: Google blocks the account out if one tries to access via any IP address other than the address it was originally established at. It may ask for a phone number or other information before unblocking the account. This behavior is not limited to Tor. If one try to use VPN or even physically move to different location with new IP address this security feature (bug) will activate. If you do not like this feature (bug) use different provider.

Comment: Hmmmm thats a problem. Unfortunately its only one provider if I want to comment on youtube vids.

Answer (score 2):

Took a while, but finally made it work:
Open the menu of the onion icon and click "Preferences...". In the window that opens select the "Security settings" tab. Uncheck "Don't record browsing history ... mode)" and "Restrict third party cookies ... data". In the content tab of the options window, uncheck "Block pop-up windows". Now you're all set to login to google+ and leave a comment. I recommend starting a new Tor session (identitiy) for the purpose of commenting videos, after which you re-check all the unchecked boxes, log out of Google+ and start a new session.